# Modified URLSession.shared to implement certificate pinning, how did they do it?

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession, backbase

On my project, we are using a closed source framework ([Backbase](https://backbase.com/), if you wanna know). This is an hybrid application framework that offers many security options "out of the box". One of them is certificate pinning, and I am quite intrigued by its implementation.

We only have to set a property in a configuration file and that's it. Every request done through `URLSession.shared` is processed through the framework and the pinning is effective. However If I instantiate my own `URLSession`, then the pinning is not effective. But I can also make the pinning effective on a new `URLSession` by instantiating it with the framework's `NSURLSessionConfiguration`.

For those who only read code:

```
// Pinning effective
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: completion)

// Pinning not effective
URLSession(configuration: .default).dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: completion)

// Pinning effective
URLSession(configuration: ShinnyFramework.getConfiguration()).dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: completion)
```

For me, `URLSession.shared` is immutable, so it was not possible to alter its working. And to implement pinning, the only way was to create a new `URLSession` with a custom `URLSessionDelegate`.

**My question is** : What did they do to get this behavior ? Method swizzling, Isa swizzling, something else ?

*Edit: I am not looking for a detailed explanation about how to implement certificate pinning. What interests me more is how to edit a supposedly immutable static property and how to configure the behavior of an `URLSession` object without using a delegate.*

Comment: Hi Hulius, are you seeking an answer from Backbase? Or just wondering about the generic way to approach this in a non-backbase way?

Comment: Hey @VonLion ! I'm particularly curious about the generic ways to implement this kind of API

Comment: Hi @Hulius, if you are interested in just a "generic ways to implement this kind of API" you could ask about how to achieve SSL Pinning in iOS without adding Backbase into the equation.

PD: I am the product owner of the Mobile SDK from Backbase.

Comment: Hi @Jbeerdev, I only spoke about Backbase to set the context of my question. My question is not really about "How to achieve SSL Pinning in iOS", which I know, but really about "How to do it this particular way", since I have never seen it implemented like that.

Comment: I don't know how they do it in Backbase but you could do this pretty easily by swizzling `URLSession.shared` to return a session with your own configuration.

Comment: @dan if you could formulate that in an answer, I'd be happy to award you the bounty :-) But.. you only have 23 hours to do so, the expiration clock is ticking